# SQL: After joined table query, put rows with data a both tables first

Tags: mysql, join

With 1001 possibilities to use MySQL, I've come up with a requirement for myself that I want to figure out, but don't know how. I also ran a Google Search of course and checked Stack Overflow and MySQL Docs, but I didn't get the answer I was looking for.

The situation:
I have 2 tables. One called and containing **customers** and one containing **customer_progress** . For your imaging, the **customer_progress** table can *optionally* contain data about the progress/status for a customer.

My goal was to join the data from the two tables, and put the customers that *do have* progress data on top, followed by the customers that do not have progress data; all in 1 query.

So I started writing a query, much like the following:

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
 customers AS c 
LEFT JOIN 
 customer_progress AS p 
ON 
 p.customer_id = c.id AND p.year = 2011 // Joining them and selecting the progress for a certain year.
WHERE 
 c.active = 1;
```

How can I put the customers that do have a progress record first, and then afterwards all the customers that do not have a progress record?

I don't know if I am going the right way with the query or that I need to approach this from a whole different angle. Using a ORDER BY made no sense.

Comment: DKinzer's answer should have worked. If it didn't consider changing your select statement to c.*,p.* just to ensure everything is selected. Also it might be a good idea to look at and post sample table data for the tables. Especially all the fields being specifically referenced in the query.

Comment: @Bryan: DKinzer was indeed right! :) My mistake was that I was too confused at the point of writing the question that I forgot to take out a 'WHERE' condition in my actual code that prevented showing the result as it should have been. Thanks to the example of DKinzer I got on the right track again. I have modified the SELECT part as well, so that I now select all the records from both tables, instead of only the customer data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select a customer progress_field that you can order by so that you add something like

`order by custer_progress_field desc`;

at the end of your select statement.

For example:

```
SELECT 
 c.filed1, p.field1 
FROM 
 customers AS c 
LEFT JOIN 
 customer_progress AS p 
ON 
 p.customer_id = c.id AND p.year = 2011 // Joining them and selecting the progress for a certain year.
WHERE 
 c.active = 1;
Order by p.field1 desc;
```

Comment: That is what I have tried (see that last sentence in my question) but it did not work out as expected.

Comment: @Sander: I don't see what you are selecting from customer_progress. 
The * is only selecting all fields from the first table not the second.

Comment: Quite right, you beat me to the answer. As a side note this should put the records with a null value for porgress at the bottem. Same with asc order. This is of course assuming that no progress means a null value for that field which it should unless your doing something odd.

Comment: you put me on the right track again!
Many thanks! I just love Stack Overflow because of this ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add something like

```
ORDER BY IF(p.customer_id IS NULL,1,0), [other fields]
// or you can do just if sorting by customer_id is acceptable 
ORDER BY p.customer_id DESC
```

You can check more details about how columns with `NULL` values are treated by `ORDER BY` on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html